# How to replicate the dynamic LOD system for characters from Messiah (2000) in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, tessellation, mesh-deformation

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15X9KNQGScE&t=316s) video on youtube and got really curious about replicating the "character system" that it covers. [This](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/behind-the-scenes-of-messiah-s-character-animation-system) article linked in the video description goes into further detail on the topic. Before I attempt to summarize, I want to disclose that I am not a graphics programmer by any means, so my grasp on many of the concepts presented in the article linked is loose. What I could gather from the article, is that the system in real time rendered a model using patch meshes which it would then tessellate based on distance from camera, performance, along with predetermined factors such as body parts and points deemed important to the silhouette. You can get an idea of this in action by watching the video.

I also want to say that my reason for pursuing this solution is almost entirely for the aesthetic. I adore the "fluid" look this gives characters as their polygons and textures shift around as a side affect of the tessellation. Not only this but as an added bonus there is so much less of a performance cost than modern tessellation methods, to my understanding. If anyone could give me some pointers as to where to look into implementing a system similar to this or that  gives a similar effect it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd question the claim that there is less performance cost to this than modern approaches. Modern tessellation is done on the GPU, so it's effectively free in terms of CPU cost. Much of the advantages this article cites are achieved today by modeling in high resolution and baking normal maps to lower-poly models, which modern tools can assist in creating more flexibly, without the onerous restriction of fitting cylindrical limb segments to models. A lot of the texture swimming effect you describe comes from the Playstation using fixed point math and lacking perspective correct texture mapping.

Comment: As you've noted, there's a lot going on in this system. More than a volunteer could explain in a single answer. At base, we can say Unity gives you the tools you need to implement such a system, by exposing a Mesh class where you can construct arbitrary meshes in code, programmable shaders where you can emulate quirks of PS1 rendering (search for existing guides and assets for that), and a LOD system that you may be able to use. But you'll need to chop this into smaller steps to get help with one step at a time. You'll need to become a graphics programmer or hire one to fully replicate this.